# swfupload limit the number of uploaded files

Tags: limit, swfupload

Is there anyway to limit the number of uploaded files in swfupload ? 
If there is no such setting in swfupload how can I check that number ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the number of uploaded files using 'file_upload_limit' property in the setting object. eg:

```
var swfu = new SWFUpload({
    upload_url : "http://www.swfupload.org/upload.php",
    flash_url : "http://www.swfupload.org/swfupload.swf",
    file_upload_limit: "10" // limit uploads to 10 files
});
```

You can use [setFileUploadLimit(file_upload_limit)](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#setFileUploadLimit) method to dynamically modify this setting.

Comment: What happens if the user reloads the page?

Comment: you can either dismiss all the already uploaded files by resetting the file_upload_limit to 10 (or any other value) each time or persist the state of the uploader in the session.